# Network errors while updating through axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I want to update event through vue axios call:

```
axios.put('/events/' + this.$route.params.id, this.form)
     .then(response => location.reload())
```

And I have route on my back end for this:

```
Route::put('/events/{event}', [\App\Http\Controllers\EventController::class, 'update']);
```

When I submit form it gets updated on database but also I get errors on network like this and page doesnt reload when I submit:

```
{message: "The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.",…}
//console errors
PUT http://localhost:8000/events 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

I cant find the way to fix this error message

Comment: It looks like the `this.$route.params.id` is an empty string. Make sure you're setting the proper ID in your route when making the request.

Answer (score 0):

Use an end line `'/'` from your front end.

```
axios.put('/events/' + this.$route.params.id + '/', this.form)
     .then(response => location.reload())
```

Comment: Did not help. I can't understand why this is appearing ```PUT http://localhost:8000/events 405 (Method Not Allowed)```

Comment: before calling this api call, did you check to console `this.$route.params.id` ?